# Why does footer style change after copying it with OpenXML from another Word document?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

When I copy the footer from a Word template to another Word document the font style and size changes in the middle paragraph of footer what consists more than one Run.
How can I copy the style of it (font style, size, etc.)? Can anyone help?

```
FooterPart srcFP = srcMDP.GetPartById(footerRef.Id) as FooterPart;
FooterPart newFooter = destMDP.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();            
newFooter.FeedData(srcFP .GetStream());
destFR.Id = destMDP.GetIdOfPart(newFooter);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy the style of the middle paragraph, too.
The middle paragraph consists multiple Runs therefore the common style elements have been raised to the level of the paragraph.